# Using a variable in a {% url %} when `app_name` has been defined

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having issues trying to use a Django template variable to form a URL in combination with the `app_name` attribute.
Currently, I am using a template variable to form a URL

```
<a href="{% url variable_name %}">On our page about {{ variable_name }}.</a>
```

Though I am aware that it is seen as good practice to make a URL more accurate by defining `app_name` in URLs. e.g.

```py
app_name = "name_of_app"
```

Meaning that URLs are then written like:

```
<a href="{% url "name_of_app:about" %}">About</a>
```

Is it possible for me to combine my current code with this approach? To use a variable and the `app_name` attribute?

I have experimented with this `{% url 'NameOfApp:'this_is_a_variable %}`, by putting the quote marks in different places, but no success yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "add" filter as such:

```
{% url "name_of_app:"|add:variable %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django convert all the template tags and variables in to plain text while rendering. We can't directly do that. Try using template filter or with tag.

Comment: That was just a mistake with my post. Thanks for highlighting that though!

Comment: is app_name variable set in app urls.py and is the app urls included in project urls.py and is the name attribute declared in respective url.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. This code works just fine,`<a href="{% url 'name_of_app:about' %}">About</a>`, but what I am trying to do is use a template variable `{{ variable }}` in the place of 'about' in `'name_of_app:about'`.

Comment: Edited the answer. did you try inserting variables.

Comment: When I try that then I receive error `Reverse for '{{ variable }}' not found. '{{ variable }}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` Though when I don't have `app_name` set and I do `<a href="{% url {{ variable }} %}">About</a>` then it works

Comment: Did you try exactly as in the answer. When Django rendering the page, it will convert all template language and variable in to plain text. I think we have to store Django variable on the above and use that variable here. Try 'Django with'

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh Try my answer, see if it works

Comment: @SivaSankar https://stackoverflow.com/a/68314864/14619040